# Feed Me not processing until sign-in

Tags: plugin-feedme

I've set up a front-end action that calls the Direct Feed URL to update content on the site, however, the feed update doesn't actually process until the control panel is accessed. Is this normal behaviour? Ideally, I need the feed to be processed as soon as the call is made, regardless of whether admin is logged in. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Feed Me adds jobs to Craft's native queue, and by default, Craft's web-based queue runner won't process that queue until a request is made to the site.

You can look at alternative (and typically more reliable) ways of processing Craft's queue here: https://nystudio107.com/blog/robust-queue-job-handling-in-craft-cms